# AWS Cloudfront not using prefix and delimiter parameters when accessing S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am attempting to serve an S3 bucket via Cloudfront to leverage the lambda@edge functionality to secure it with SSO.

I'm able to setup the access to the bucket via Cloudfront, however when using the delimiter and prefix url parameters the whole bucket listing is returned.
An example of my URL - https://foobar.cloudfront.net/?delimiter=/&prefix=data/

The bucket is in eu-west-1 and cannot be moved to another region. My cloudfront origin config is the following:

- Origin domain: my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com (used this instead of the region specific URL in an attempt to have it work)
- Origin access: Origin access control settings
- Origin access control: sign requests, origin type s3
- No origin shield or additional settings

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by setting the behaviour origin request policy to "AllViewerExceptHostHeader"